# Объединить в один массив

Tags: javascript

Как объединить все вложенные массивы в один и если будут повторяющиеся элементы, то убрать их. Например 12,13 буду встречаться в итоговом едином массиве один раз. Массив генерируется с сервера, так-что нужен будет универсальный цикл

```
var arr = [
  [23, 26, 37, 38, 43, 44],
  [12, 13, 23, 26, 33, 34, 37, 38, 43, 44],
  [12, 13, 23, 26, 33, 34, 37, 38, 43, 44]
];
```

Comment: объединить в 1 массив -> сделать множеством (ps не знаю есть ли в js такая возможность,но по сути должна быть)

Comment: @TEA, уже есть, впрочем не так давно.

Comment: @Qwertiy, в принципе уже довольно давно :)

Answer (score 5):

Если используется достаточно современный стандарт, то можно очень легко сделать вот так:

```js
var arr = [
  [23, 26, 37, 38, 43, 44],
  [12, 13, 23, 26, 33, 34, 37, 38, 43, 44],
  [12, 13, 23, 26, 33, 34, 37, 38, 43, 44]
];

var res = Array.from(new Set(arr.flat()));

console.log(res.join(" "));
```

Comment: а избежать дублирования элементов?

Comment: @stiv, а где ты увидел дублирование?

Comment: Невнимательно посмотрел, всё хорошо

Answer (score 0):

Если хочется сделать самостоятельно в синтаксисе ES5 (обращаю внимание, что для проверки наличия элемента он приводится к строке, что означает неприменимость этого кода к объектам и необходимость внимательно отнестись к наличию смешанных типов в массиве , в том числе null и undefined):

```js
var arr = [
  [23, 26, 37, 38, 43, 44],
  [12, 13, 23, 26, 33, 34, 37, 38, 43, 44],
  [12, 13, 23, 26, 33, 34, 37, 38, 43, 44]
];

var res = [], has = Object.create(null);

for (var q=0; q<arr.length; ++q) {
  for (var w=0; w<arr[q].length; ++w) {
    if (!has[arr[q][w]]) {
      has[arr[q][w]] = true;
      res.push(arr[q][w]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(res.join(" "));
```

Comment: тут похоже даже не ES5, а ES3

Comment: @Grundy, `Object.create(null)` - это ES5. В ES3 пришлось бы обходиться `{}`.

Comment: и в данном случае вполне можно было им и обойтись :-)

Comment: @Grundy, тогда `if` пенреписывать надо, а то вдруг кто-то `"toString"` посложит в массив. Ну и с `"__proto__"` вообще печально.